# How many entries in PDB have SS bonds?

Tags: proteins, database, protein-structure, pdb

Is there a way to figure out what percentage of entries in PDB have SS bonds?
In addition, what other types of bonds in PDB may be worth looking into (not H bonds)?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to check annotations in mmCIF or PDB files.

Looking at my page with [statistics of mmCIF tags](https://project-gemmi.github.io/pdb-stats/tags.html), last updated in March:

```
_struct_conn_type.id        59137×metalc 42706×covale 36195×disulf 10725×hydrog
_struct_conn.conn_type_id   5350402×hydrog 1733277×metalc 559092×covale 226472×disulf
```

Which means 226472 disulfide bonds in 36195 PDB entries at the time when the PDB had 161470 entries.

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly what I needed.
What about ionic interaction (salt bridges), do you have the numbers?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can't help with salt bridges.